# What is the current grouped bar chart in the development branch that's in verson 3.0.11?

Tags: dc.js

I see two versions in two other branches, but was there one integrated into the development branch?

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart that will group by keys in multi-key dimension if possible, then show x labels based on the keys so for a 3 key dimension there will be 3 x-labels, one is the last dimension key, the second is label when grouped by the second dimension key and finally the third by the first dimension key. Possible having brackets for each after the first label that is by each child/element.
Is this possible in dc right now without making it yourself by using d3.js?

I'm hoping it'd be something similar in a sense to colorAccessor that can color by key like this:

```
.colorAccessor(function (dim, colors) {
return [dim.key[2], colors.key];
})
```

I do see some issues in GitHub that address this in a different way, but are older then never resolved and either are in a different branch or only show it in one group with one x label.

Comment: As I commented on GitHub, this feature hasn't been merged because the implementation would make dc.js difficult to maintain. You have to use the branch, [as detailed in this comment](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1459#issuecomment-426482565). AFAIK d3-axis doesn't support hierarchical ticks, so you'd have to hack that part yourself.

Comment: [Link to further discussion](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1519).